# how to introduce libraries as local class like wiremock-jre8-standalone?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

wiremock-jre8-standalone has not any lib in its library ,but it has a lot of other packages' classes. How can I do like it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are noticing that [wiremock-standalone](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone) does not have any library dependencies, but rather includes them all in the same jar.

This approach is known as a "fat jar" (or sometimes "über jar"). Creating one depends on what build tool you use, and you have tagged your question with both Gradle and Maven.

For Gradle, use the [Shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/). For Maven, use the [Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). There are plenty of guides out there to help you get started.